# Determining Read Groups

Tags: sequence-alignment, sam, bwa, picard

Which Read Groups are correct:

```
java -Xmx4G -jar picard.jar AddOrReplaceReadGroups \
I=$SNIC_TMP/WCRO84_S23_L005.bam \
O=WCRO84_S23_L005.bam \
RGID=WCRO84_S23_L005 \
RGLB=WCRO84 \
RGPL=illumina \
RGPU=WCRO84_S23_L005 \
RGSM=WCRO84
```

or

```
java -Xmx4G -jar picard.jar AddOrReplaceReadGroups \
I=$SNIC_TMP/WCRO84_S23_L005.bam \
O=WCRO84_S23_L005.bam \
RGID=WCRO84_S23_L005 \
RGLB=WCRO84_S23_L005 \
RGPL=illumina \
RGPU=WCRO84_S23_L005 \
RGSM=WCRO84_S23_L005
```

Or is a better way to determine read groups?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 4):

Usually it doesn't actually matter, but if you want it to be very correct:

```
RGID=SomeLibraryID \
RGLB=SomeLibraryID \
RGPL=illumina \
RGPU=Some_Sequencer_ID \
RGSM=SomeSampleID
```

That assumes you have one library per sample and aren't splitting the output BAM files by lane.

Comment: Is it possible to get it automatically determine by reading the FASTQ header or filename?

Comment: If you have control of how the data is produced then yes, you can set all of that automatically. Otherwise you can't be certain the file/read names are meaningful.